# MySQL: Multiple queries with one output

Tags: mysql, sql

Looking at the various post, I'm still struggling with creation of one query. I'm trying to get out put of a Users progression within a course. Here is my DB Setup.

```
COURSE TABLE:
(CourseID | Product |  CourseName | TotalModules | CreationDate)

MODULE TABLE:
(ModuleID | Product | ModuleName | TotalPages | CreationDate)

MODULECOURSEASSOCIATION TABLE:
(CourseID | ModuleID | CreationDate)

User TABLE:
(UserID | StudentEmail | CreationDate)

PROGRESSION TABLE:
(ProgressionID | ModuleID | UserID | PageNumber, CreationDate)
```

The Progression Table records beside the ProgressionIDs, which Module the User has seen, and associated date. What I want to accomplish is this:

Have one total page progression count on a course level.

I.E. A CourseID "1", maybe have 3 Modules. Each of the 3 modules has 3 pages associated with it. So a total of 9 pages all together for Course "A" in ProductID = 2.

UserID "1" has seen Page 1, Page 2, Page 3 in the first Module in ProductID = 2. The progression count should then be 30%. How do I write this in a query?

I tried this:

```
SELECT count(1) AS TotalModulesCompleted 
FROM (select count(PageNumber) AS NumPages,
      (select TotalPages 
      from Module, ModuleCourseAssociation 
      where Module.ModuleID = ModuleCourseAssociation.ModuleID and 
      ModuleCourseAssociation.CourseID = 1 and Module.ProductID = 2) AS TotalPages, 
      (select CourseID from ModuleCourseAssociation
       where ModuleCourseAssociation.ModuleID = Progression.ModuleID
       and CourseID=8) AS CourseID
FROM Progression WHERE UserID = 11 GROUP by ModuleID) 
CourseProgression
WHERE NumPages = TotalPages;
```

I'm rather lost. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you add a sqlfiddle?

Comment: Can you please add table creation/inserts scripts or add it to sqlfiddle.com as @bish mentioned?

Comment: Yes, let me get this going. I just need the definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you require this information per course for one particular student.

You have requested a percentage complete. Therefore you will require two pieces of information from the query:

- Total pages in course
- Total pages that user has read

With this in mind, the following should work provided that the database is correctly loaded:

```
SELECT
  c.CourseID
  ,c.CourseName
  ,SUM(m.TotalPages) AS CourseTotalPages
  ,SUM(up.PageNumber) AS UserTotalPages
  ,SUM(up.PageNumber) / SUM(m.TotalPages) AS UserPercentageComplete
FROM `Course` c
JOIN `ModuleCourseAssociation` cm ON c.CourseID = cm.CourseID
JOIN `Module` m ON cm.ModuleID = m.ModuleID
LEFT JOIN `Progression` up ON m.ModuleID = up.ProgressionID
LEFT JOIN `User` u ON up.UserID = u.UserID
WHERE c.ProductID = 2
  AND (u.UserID = 11 OR u.UserID IS NULL)    -- Cats or nothing
GROUP BY c.CourseID
  ,c.CourseName
```

I have provided an SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbeca/6/0).

Comment: This is fantastic, you got to it before I could do the Fiddle. Thank you so much for the work. The query returns all CourseID vs Module Page Count. This worked but not the progression statuses (UserTotalPages, UserPercentageComplete). I got only partially done what you did...I'll play with it to get the progression.  Thank you all.

Comment: I'll have another playaround at an opportune time.